# Logcat error-Content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Tags: java, android

My list view is showing error like this what i mention in my question,eventhough i mention in mainactivity extends listactivity also and my layout i put as listview

activity_list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);   
        initView();   
    }

    private void initView() {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/test/apps.php";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        setListAdapter(adapter);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    }
}
```

My log cat error is showing like this

```
5-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jsonandroid/com.example.jsonandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at com.example.jsonandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-17 11:30:30.649: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: try after cleaning your project.

Comment: Off the cuff, what you have looks OK. Bear in mind that if your activity layout is just a full-screen `ListView`, you can skip the activity layout and the `setContentView()` call. `ListActivity` will automatically give you a full-screen `ListView` by default.

Comment: try android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: after cleaning also it comes the problem@SankarV,

Comment: @IBetterCommunity your Code seems to be ok...Do one thing Take adapter as field and instantiate it with some ArrayList ,bind Adapter to list and then `onFetchComplete` call `adpater.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: i cant get you,could you edit my code and give answer to my problem@Pragnani

Answer (score 0):

you just have to change the id of you list view in activity_list_item.xml to @android:id/list If you use a ListActivity you listview id must be like mentionned

Comment: Ummm... I think that is what the OP already has for `android:id` on the `ListView`.

Comment: take a loook at this link http://www.mokasocial.com/2010/08/listactivity-and-missing-android-r-id-list/

Comment: ya i put as listactivity and i mention in my listview also like that android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: i checked all the way,but again its showing the error in logcat as same@CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout to,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: @Basim Sherif : no. why do you think this would be any better, btw?

Comment: @IBetterCommunity : that's trivially because of the extra intendation at the begining of the file

Comment: what it might be the solution for my problem

Comment: You have to replace your layout with this one.replace all your xml code in your layout with above code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to `setContentView`.

`ListActivity` does not require that you assign a layout to it via the setContentView() method, if you only want to show a ListView ListActivity contains by default a ListView.

In case you need to include more Views than a ListView in your ListActivity you can still assign a layout to your activity. In this case your layout must contain a ListView with the `android:id` attribute set to `@android:id/list`.

Comment: i removed the line and after i run it,but its showing Invalid response http://www.semurjengkol.com/populating-android-listview-with-json-based-data-fetched-from-mysql-server-using-php/ this is the link i tried

Comment: what it mean **Invalid response**? Have your original problem solved?

Comment: I comment out the setcontentview line,and then i run my progam,in the emulator its loading and then in the screen its showing invalid response,could you check the link  http://www.semurjengkol.com/populating-android-listview-with-json-based-data-fetched-from-mysql-server-using-php/ ,this link i am following just now i am trying to do the link steps

Comment: i.e., that is you are getting `JSONException`. So it is showing "Invalid Respoonse". I think the original question have been solved and now its getting diverted. The best way is to open a new question with more details for the new problem

Comment: Dude i am doing that example only,try to get the output for that example,but they are mention the answer but why cant we get,i followed the each and every step of that example,i have one doubt,it  might be url problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609113/look-at-example-belowed-link-i-mention-i-try-to-solve-the-example-its-showing-in  see this question also i mention there

Comment: dude i have one doubt why we remove the set contentview in our code@Sankar v